# Possible to convert string date to mysql DateTime?

Tags: c#, mysql, string, datetime

I am working on a program that gets a list of file names from a directory, then parses the file names into individual variables (strings) and converts it into something that can be submitted to a mysql database that will the later be queued for searches.

In those file names contain a 4 digit year, 2 digit day, 2 digit month, 2 digit hour, and 4 digit minute (##AM/PM), followed by 2 numbers that can be between 3 and 11 digits.

I have parsed the filename and formatted the date and time info into the following string: YYYY/DD/MM HH:MMAM or YYYY/DD/MM HH:MMPM (only "AM" and "PM" changes on minutes).

**EX:** 2014/24/12 02:50PM

**How can I convert the string into DateTime to submit into a MySql database.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function does what you need.

```
STR_TO_DATE('2014/24/12 02:50PM', '%Y/%d/%m %h:%i%p')
```

gives the result you need. You can look up the [format codes here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 1):

Using DateTime.ParseExact will do the trick to get it into .net's DateTime object:

```
        string s = "2014/24/12 02:50PM";
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy/dd/MM hh:mmtt", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ;
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

Comment: when I submit the dt to the database, it submits as: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: What is the date format your mySQL database accepts? You can convert it as needed in the ToString method's parameters, ex: `dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`